# Newbie: Are filters the right place to modify the response data, based on request parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, controller

My question is very simple: In an averagely complex web request, usually we have quite a lot of information in terms of request parameters. In many cases some of those parameters are such that the controller action should not ever even be interested in, such as for example referrer_id, (for analytics purposes) if the request came from clicking a link on a third-party website, or from an email newsletter.

Another example: On quora, if you enter the following url:
http://www.quora.com/As-a-mobile-apps-developer-on-what-platform-should-I-choose-to-develop-and-why
you will be led to the normal web page, however, if you enter the same url, but with the (**snids**=24082824) parameter at the end, you get the page content, plus some additional overlaying content (In this case, information about who edited the question last)

I think to it would be stupid to check for the existence and values of every single request parameter in the controller action. That would urn the action in an if-else if-else soup.

Filters seem a much better alternative to break and decouple all the varying elements of a request, right? Using filters, once could completely change the workflow in mere seconds, without breaking and messing with controller actions. Controller actions are there to grab a view based on the url pattern of the request, but it is a duty of the filters to modify the request/response, intercept, log, or even override controller actions, if there is some more parameter sugar in the request, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes filters is the right way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Just a small note, I wouldnt use filters to modify the request and response. It is possible given that those objects are available to the filters. Using filters to do small time things that would keep the actions clean, or enforce access controls specific to an application sounds nice. But if its about modifying the request and response then I would prefer a custom Rack middleware. After all every rails app is a rack app.

Comment: See, this is where my experience with Rails ends. I am a complete noob, so I guess I will have to research more on Rack. Thanks, for pointing that out.

Comment: For things like redirecting depending on whether the user is new or not logged in filters are fine, but for some serious request mangling I suppose rack middleware is the way to go. Check some stuff on filters http://rails.nuvvo.com/lesson/6373-action-controller-filters

Comment: I find that for most things centered around users (ie application logic) rack middleware is a bit too low-level and solutions become too complex. But for other things it's good. I use it to dynamically serve different content for different domain names. Here's a reference http://asciicasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware

Comment: Now that I got a bit more familiar with Rack as well, I also think it is a bit of a too low level stuff. Pointing to the quora example I gave in my question, I still think that this is better going to be served by a filter. Good about filters is that they also alleviate the coupling issues, but do not take the request/response flow completely out of the app level. On the contrary their actions are still localized in the controller, and this is exactly what I would like to keep